# Upcoming singular they and verb + s/es

Tags: verb-agreement, singular-they

> The user taps a link, then grabs their mouse.

Is this correct? Or should one use “tap” and “grab”?

My instinct is to mix “taps” and “grab”, due to the latter’s closeness to “their”, but I doubt such a mix is correct.

Comment: Since you know that "user" and "their" are both singular, isn't the answer obvious?

Comment: @KillingTime Since I went to the trouble of creating an account and figuring out how to best ask my question, isn’t your question dubious? Hint: not everyone speaks English as their first language.

Comment: "The user **taps** a link," yes. Simple fixes include 1-"then grabs **the** mouse." Or, 2- "Users tap a link, then grab their mouse." Or, 3-"Tap a link, then grab your mouse." It is standard in IT to switch to plural 'users' and write in the second person with no pronouns at all (no he/she, no his/hers.)

Comment: @YosefBaskin None of your fixes sound right, “the mouse” is awkward, it’s their mouse. My sentence is in the context of computer code dealing with one user’s interactions (in their browser), so pluralizing the user doesn’t sound right either. (I’m also confused at singular they declared to be acceptable but then potentially needing “fixes”.)

Comment: Let me address singular declared acceptable but then potentially needing fixes. I avoid the singular they, but was trying to help you within your own structure. That's politeness, saying you're not wrong but offering improvements. Since commenting code is rare, you are ahead of the game to write your original sentence. Again, polite.

Comment: What does the user use to tap the link?  Before grabbing the mouse?

Comment: @Xanne Their finger and touchscreen. Touching a link then using their mouse/trackpad is rare but can happen, for instance if it seems using touch didn’t have the desired effect.

Comment: Seems a near-duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/471314/usage-singular-vs-plural-for-in-their-hands-and-on-their-face although that is about singular nouns not singular verbs

Comment: More about nouns https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/584255/when-using-their-as-a-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-should-a-noun-that-foll https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114077/singular-noun-objects-of-plural-subjects

Answer (score 5):

(Your user name looks French, so I shall draw an analogy to French grammar that might help you better understand the English situation.)

Should we use a **plural** verb with the French subject pronoun *on* when it means "we"? No, we should not, for *on ne ❌ **savons** pas* would be utterly wrong – it must be *on ne sait pas*. It doesn’t matter that logically *on* is standing in for a first person plural, as grammatically it is always a third person singular, which is the type of verb it must therefore take.

This is the same class of error as you made here, but in English, which I demonstrate by my next sentence following this one. `-->` *"You ❌ **has**"* misunderstood the thing that we misleadingly label "singular *they*", as this very example that uses "singular you" demonstrates: the subject pronouns *you* and *they* ALWAYS command a PLURAL verb for correct grammatical concord. Calling them "singular *they*" and "singular *you*" in this way has tricked you.

This is just like how the French "plural *on*" always commands a **singular** verb — because *on* can only be grammatically singular even when notionally plural in some underlying thematic sense.

In the exact same way, English "singular *you*" and "singular *they*" always command **plural** verbs — because *they* and *you* can only be grammatically plural even when notionally singular in sense.

Comment: Thanks but I’m not really sure that answers my question. Are you saying that it should thus be “the user tap”, even though it’s unclear the user is “they” at this point?

Comment: @AlexandreDieulot No, I'm saying that it must always be *the user taps*  but if you refer back to them later, you say that *they tap*.

Answer (score 2):

To address some of the comments: First, it's a sensible question, as a singular 'they' does not make a sentence starting with "They grabs the X..." sound correct. Second, there is no need to contort yourself to avoid singular "they" - you'll just end up sounding unnatural.

With those out of the way, you are correct in identifying that there are contradictory grammatical conventions pushing on verb conjugations for singular "they" right now. It feels (to me, a native AmEng speaker, older coastal cohort) that one maintains concord for words that are nearby, even if this creates a clash at a distance. So, your

> The user taps a link, then grabs their mouse.

sounds best. But notice that a minor change in the wording leads to

> The user taps a link, then they grab their mouse.

as sounding best if you add a pronoun to the second clause. But don't be surprised if this answer goes out-of-date quickly.

(Note: These are for singular "they" being used to refer to a non-specific person. There are people who prefer to be referred to as "they" when being specifically referred to, and I have no idea what's proper in their case.)

Comment: I always recommend that answers include citations from reliable sources instead of relying on "feelings" alone or subjective judgments of what "sounds best."

Comment: The factual parts of this answer are good, but I don't see the need to speculate about future language changes. Of course, any answer on this site *could* be invalidated in decades' or centuries' time by the evolution of English, and I see no evidence that a change to the conjugation of sentences involving "they" is any more likely than any other possible change. For example, I'm not aware of any current dialect in which this answer does not apply.